# Spring data - Count distinct items from grouping

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-mongodb

I have db of visits users to places, that contains place_id and user_id like this

```
{place_id : 1, user_id : 1}
{place_id : 1, user_id : 1}
{place_id : 1, user_id : 2}
{place_id : 2, user_id : 3}
{place_id : 2, user_id : 3}
```

And I want to get amount of distinct users in each place. I ended up with following native mongo aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
        $group: {
            _id: "$place_id",
            setOfUsers: {
                $addToSet: "$user_id"
            }
        }
    }, {
        $project: {
            distinctUserCount: {
                $size: "$setOfUsers"
            }
        }
    }])
```

And now I want to implement it using Spring Data, the problem now is $size operation in projection, since Spring data API does not have such, at least I haven't found it in reference.

```
    GroupOperation group = Aggregation.group("place_id").addToSet("user_id").as("setOfUsers");
    ProjectionOperation project = Aggregation.project(). .... ?
```

Maybe there is any way to create size field also, than the nested api can be used:

```
Aggregation.project().and("distinctUserCount").nested( ???);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to answer this in "one hit", so rather than address your "$project" issue, I'm going to advise here that there is a better approach.

The [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) operator will create a "unique" array ( or "set" ) of the elements you ask to add to it. It is however basically another form of [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) in itself, with the difference being the elements are added to an "array" ( or "set" ) in results.

This is "bad" for scalability, as your potential problem here is that the "set" actually exceeds the BSON limit for document size. Maybe it does not right now, but who knows what the code you write right now will be doing in ten years time.

Therefore, since `$group` is really the same thing, and you also need "two" pipeline stages to get the "distinct" count, then just to "two" `$group` stages instead:

```
    Aggregation pipeline = newAggregation(
        group(fields("place_id","user_id")),
        group("_id.place_id").count().as("distinctUserCount")
    );
```

Being the shell equivalent of:

```
[
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { "place_id": "$place_id", "user_id": "$user_id" }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.place_id",
        "distinctUserCount": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
]
```

This is simple code and it is much more "scalable" as the individualt "user_id" values are at first contained in separate documents in the pipeline. Therefore the "second" `$group` ( in place of a $project with $size ) "counts" the distinct amounts that were already determined in the first grouping key.

Learn the limitations and pitfalls, and code well.

Comment: I was thinking about 2 pipeline stages, but I wasn't smart enough to create a composed key based on both identifiers. Thanks for answer.

Comment: @IgorPiddubnyi Whatever way you view it, it's still two pipeline stages, even with a `$project`. But a double `$group` is far more efficient. I have code from "custom" pipeline stages where needed, so your intial idea is possible. But this really is better anyway. Hence why I answered this way.